# iPad - Inegrating Blurb in my app

Tags: ipad

Blurb is really a good way to publish images/text as photos.
Is there any API/Library/SDK from Blurb that I can integrate in my iPad app and create the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any API for Blurb to integrate in iOS